# How can I get Public IP of my FARGATE ECS task with metadata endpoint or java sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metadata, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to get public IP of my fargate ECS task after container started.
I get IPv4Addresses when requested http://169.254.170.2/v2/metadata/ but I don't get public IP of task.

When I use runTask(request) method of RunTaskResult, again I don't get public IP from RunTaskResult.

Is there a way to get public IP of my fargate task something like  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname (for EC2)?

Comment: Did you clarify in the taskdefinition that it needs a public ip?

Comment: I set enable Auto-assign public IP when run task.

Comment: Assign public IP for a task? Is not it insecure?

Comment: Task have security group @Oleksandr_DJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem with DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest.I get private IP of my container with **curl http://169.254.170.2/v2/metadata/** then run this code.

```
    AmazonEC2 ec2AsyncClient= AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new 
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();

    DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest request = new DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest();
    request.withFilters(new Filter().withName("private-ip-address").withValues("my-container-private-Ip"));
    DescribeNetworkInterfacesResult result = ec2AsyncClient.describeNetworkInterfaces(request);
    String publicIP = result.getNetworkInterfaces().get(0).getAssociation().getPublicDnsName();
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I fear that finding the first ENI with a random private IP address will not scale well - with enough instances, you will eventually get multiple ENIs in the response. I addedd a match by MAC address, which I think should be unique enough.

Comment: My code (using the async client) looks like this: `ec2.describeNetworkInterfaces(b -> b.filters(Filter.builder().name("addresses.private-ip-address").values(privateIpAddress).build(), Filter.builder().name("mac-address").values(mac).build())).thenApply(res -> res.networkInterfaces().stream().map(eni -> eni.association().publicDnsName()).findFirst().orElse(null));` (it could probably benefit some formatting not in a comment...)